# How to pass Dynamic Props through Routes in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-props

I can send static `props` via `<router-link>` like so:

**`parent-component`**:

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'child-component'}"></router-link>
```

**`child-component`**:

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ test }}</h1>
</template>


<script setup>
import {defineProps} from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
    test: String
})
</script>
```

**`router.js`**:

```
const router = createRouter({
    routes: [
        {path: "/child-component", name: "child-component", component: ChildComponent, props: {test: 'hello world'}},
    ]
});
```

This correctly displays `hello world` in the `h1` element in `child-component`. But how do I pass a dynamic element, say a `state` or `prop` (parent) through the route?

I've tried:

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'child-component'}" :props="{test: 'did this come through?'}"></router-link>
```

or

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'child-component'}" :test="'did this come through?'"></router-link>
```

But I don't know what to put instead of `hello world`:

```
const router = createRouter({
    routes: [
        {path: "/child-component", name: "child-component", component: ChildComponent, props: {test: 'hello world'}},
    ]
});
```

Comment: Usually, you pass either `params` or `query` to a router: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#navigate-to-a-different-location

Comment: As I could understand from [Vue router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components), props is used for accessing route data (like ```params```) in an easier and better way. If you have a route with path like ```"/child-component"``` you do not necessarily needs props like that. Use data or other Vue facilities in parent component and pass them via **normal props** to child component.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is,
**Router link**

```
 <router-link
  :to="{
         name: 'child-component',
         params: { id: id, name: name },
        }" >test
</router-link>
```

// Id and name are dynamic value

route.js file

```
const router = createRouter({
    routes: [
        {path: "/child-component/:id/:name", name: "child-component", component: ChildComponent},
    ]
})
```

You can access the params at the child component

```
 <span>Name: {{ $route.params.name }} Id: {{ $route.params.id }}
 </span>
```